# Send SMS via NFC

Tags: android, nfc

I have contactless nfc card. Can I send SMS to my Sim card in phone from
 this card ?

Comment: In what way is this related to programming? Stackoverflow is dedicated to questions related to programming - please keep questions [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and consider asking on a more appropriate [Stack Exchange Site](http://stackexchange.com/sites)

Comment: OK,I'm thinking about find a way to programming it. program send sms via nfc to a android app/sim card.. Thank you vey much for your comment

Comment: ah i see ... ok would have helped if you had specified your intentions in your question but that's academic now.. seems you have your answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, You can send/receive SMS only via GSM network.